# Create regex from variable with capture groups in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

How can I create a regex from a variable so that it has a capture group that can then be used in a `replace()` call?

The below is what I have tried so far without success.

```js
var term = 'test'
var r = new RegExp('('+term+')', "ig");

$('#test').html( $('#test').html().replace(r, '<span class="found">'+$1+'</span>') ); // Uncaught ReferenceError: $1 is not defined
```

```css
.found{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">This is a test</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this is working as you expect? The main thing is to use `$1` inside the replacement string, as `<span class="found">$1</span>`.

```js
var term = 'test'
var r = new RegExp('('+term+')', "ig");

$('#test').html( $('#test').html().replace(r, '<span class="found">$1</span>') );
```

```css
.found{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">This is a test</div>
```

You may also discard the capturing group and use the [`$&` backreference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) in the string replacement pattern that refers to the whole match and also [*escape*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) the search string since in case it contains [special regex chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions), it may fail to match:

```js
var term = 'test+test'
var r = new RegExp(term.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), "ig");

$('#test').html( $('#test').html().replace(r, '<span class="found">$&</span>') );
```

```css
.found{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">This is a test+test</div>
```

Comment: Yes :). Also, have a look at "Using Parenthesized Substring Matches" at MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), this is very helpful.

Comment: This approach will fall over if `term` contains any parentheses, so you'll have to escape them with something like `term.replace(/\(/g, "\\(").replace(/\)/g, "\\)")`... and the same for `[]` and of course \ itself. See this answer for a general solution to regex term sanitising (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/153702).

Comment: @Extragorey I can't see how your comment is relevant: my second code snippet shows exactly how to deal with special characters (*`var r = new RegExp(term.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), "ig");`*). This question was basically about replacing a regex match with itself, escaping special chars was an additional enhancement in case OP had to deal with special characters. It is not always the case.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew All good, just thought I'd enhance the answer for people like me who need it.

Comment: @Extragorey Then the codereview link can be replaced with an [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/3832970),  I consider that escaping code the cleanest.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap replace expression with a function.

```js
var term = 'test'
var r = new RegExp('('+term+')', "ig");

$('#test').html( $('#test').html().replace(r, function($1){return '<span class="found">'+$1+'</span>'}) ); // Uncaught ReferenceError: $1 is not defined
```

```css
.found{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">This is a test</div>
```